# Use combination of _.invoke and function parameters in JS

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have this code:

```
var complete = _.invoke([settings, permissions], 'fetch');
```

However, I need to run them both with a parameter, like so:

`settings.fetch({
async: false
})`

and the same for permissions.

How can I pass `async: false` into an `_.invoke` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[_.invoke](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke) will forward additional arguments :

> **invoke** _.invoke(list, methodName, [*arguments])
>   Calls the method
>   named by *methodName* on each value in the *list*. Any extra arguments
>   passed to invoke will be forwarded on to the method invocation.

Try

```
var complete = _.invoke([settings, permissions], 'fetch', {async: false});
```

Comment: You should have just told me to RTFM ; )

Comment: @benhowdle89 Nah, that's not nice :)

Comment: But the *F* in *RTFM* means *fine* so no swearing is needed :)